# Can anyone spot the problem in my for loop in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics

I have a text file which contains [a protein sequence in FASTA format](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P51170.fasta). FASTA files have the first line which is a header and the rest is the sequence of interest. Each letter is one amino acid. I want to write a program that finds the motifs VSEX (X being any amino acid and the others being specific ones) and prints out the motif itself and the position it was found. This is my code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
open (IN,'P51170.fasta.txt');
while(<IN>) {
$seq.=$_;
$seq=~s/ //g;
chomp $seq;
} 
#print $seq;

$j=0;
$l= length $seq;
#print $l;
for ($i=0, $i<=$l-4,$i++){
    $j=$i+1;
    $motif= substr ($seq,$i,4);
    if ($motif=~m/VSE(.)/) {
        print "motif $motif found in position $j \n" ;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I have messed up the loop, but I don't know what went wrong. The output I get on cygwin is the following:

```
motif  found in position 2
motif  found in position 2
motif  found in position 2
```

Comment: In addition to correcting the for loop as instructed in the answers, you should remove the header before calculating the positions by discarding the first line (or any lines beginning with '>').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So some general perl tips:

Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;` - that'll tell you when your code is doing something bogus.

Anyway, in trying to figure out what's going wrong (although the other post correctly points out that perl `for` loops need semicolons not commas) I rewrote it a little to accomplish what I think is the same result:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#read in source data
open (my $input_data,' '<', P51170.fasta.txt') or die $!;    
#extract 'first line':
#>sp|P51170|SCNNG_HUMAN Amiloride-sensitive sodium channel subunit gamma OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SCNN1G PE=1 SV=4

my $header = <$input_data>;
#slurp all the rest of the file into the seq string.  
#$/ is the 'end of line' separate, thus we temporarily undefine it to read the whole file rather than just one line
my $seq = do { local $/; <$input_data> };
#remove linefeeds from the sequence
$seq =~ s/[\r\n]//g;
close $input_data;


#printing what either looks like for clarity
print $header, "\n\n";   
print $seq, "\n\n";


#iterate regex matches against $seq
while ( $seq =~ m/VSE(.)/g ) {
    # use pos() function to report where matches happened. $1 is the contents
    # of the first 'capture bracket'. 
    print "motif $1 at ", pos($seq), "\n";
}
```

So rather than manually for-looping through your data, we instead use the regex engine and the perl `pos()` function to find where any relevant matches occur.

Answer (score 2):

Use semicolons in the C-style loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$l-4; $i++) {
```

Or, use a Perl style loop:

```
for my $i (0 .. $l - 4) {
```

But you don't have to loop over the positions, Perl can do that for you (see [pos](https://perldoc.pl/pos)):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

open my $in, '<', 'P51170.fasta.txt' or die $!;
my $seq = "";
while (<$in>) {
    chomp;
    s/ //g;
    $seq .= $_;
}

while ($seq =~ /(VSE.)/g) {
    say "Motif $1 found at ", pos($seq) - 3;
}
```

Note that I followed some good practices:

- I used [strict](https://perldoc.pl/strict) and [warnings](https://perldoc.pl/warnings);
- I checked the return value of `open`;
- I used the 3-argument version of `open`;
- I used a lexical filehandle;
- I don't remove spaces from $seq again and again, only from the newly read lines.

Comment: You don't have to initialize `$seq` if you use `.=`.

Comment: @TLP Depends on what you want for an empty file.

Comment: @ikegami In case of an empty file it would seem better with an uninitialized warning than a blank output.

Answer (score 1):

Your base program can be reduced to a one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -nwE's/\s+//g; say "motif $1 found at " . pos while /VSE(.)/g' P51170.fasta.txt
```

- `-0777` is slurp mode: the whole file is read in one go
- `-n` uses either standard input, or a file name as argument as source for input
- `-E` enable features (`say` in this case)
- `s/\s+//g` removes all whitespace from the default variable `$_` -- the input from the file
- `$1` contains the string matched by the parentheses in the regex
- `pos` reports the position of the match

Though of course this includes the header in the offset, which I assume you do not want. So we're going to have to skip the slurp mode `-0777` and the `-n` switch. It will clutter the code somewhat:

```
perl -wE'$h = <>; $_ = do { local $/; <> }; s/\s+//g; say "motif $1 found at " . pos while /VSE(.)/g' P51170.fasta.txt
```

Here we use the idiomatic `do` block slurp in combination with the diamond operator `<>`. The diamond operator will use either standard input, or a file name, just like `-n`.

The first `<>` reads the header, which can be used later.

The one-liner as a program file looks like this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;                 # never skip these pragmas
use feature 'say';

my $h = <>;                   # header, skip for now
$_ = do { local $/; <> };     # slurp rest of file
s/\s+//g;                     # remove whitespace
say "motif $1 found at " . pos while /VSE(.)/g;
```

Use it like this:

```
perl fasta.pl P51170.fasta.txt
```